# Start and Stop broadcastReceiver from activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I created a broadcastReceiver

in manifest

```
<receiver android:name="SMSMonitor">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

class:

```
public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                bodyText.append(message.getMessageBody());
            }
            String body = bodyText.toString();
            Observer.getInstance().send(new SmsEvent(body));
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
```

When started my app receiver starts to wortk. But I have 2 buttons in activity "start" and "stop". I want to start receiver when i press "start" button and stop when press "stop" button. How can i do it?

Comment: Did you tried `registerReceiver(...)` method?

Comment: I dont understand you now...how registerReceiver(...) method?

Comment: You can dynamically register a receiver with `Context.registerReceiver()`

Answer (score 3):

**Call this method in `onClick()` of start**

```
 public void enableBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, SMSMonitor.class);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Toast.makeText(this, 'Enabled broadcast receiver', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

**Call this method in `onClick()` of stop**

```
    // This method disables the Broadcast receiver registered in the AndroidManifest file.
    * @param view
    */
   public void disableBroadcastReceiver(){
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, SMSMonitor class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(this, 'Disabled broadcst receiver', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Comment: What about manifest? now if i open app receiver start automaticly

Answer (score 0):

try this,

in your manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="your receiver name">
```

in main Activity

BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.w("Check", "Inside On Receiver");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(broadcast, intentFilter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcast);
    }
}
```